# Angular routing fails after refresh (angular route same name as server route)

Tags: angular, express, routes, mean-stack

I'm having a peculiar problem with Angular (version 5) in which I have some routes set up in angular like so:

```js
{path: 'calendar',  canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: ProjectsComponent }
{path: 'map',  canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: MapComponent }
```

Then in my web page header there are buttons that will activate these routes.

```html
<li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/calendar']">Kalender</a></li>
<li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/map']">Kaart</a></li>
```

All is good for /calendar but for /map there is a problem.
At first clicking /map button loads the component which then sends a get request to the server api for some data with a token being sent for authentication, no worries.

When I refresh though (or manually type localhost:3000/map), the angular app does not pick up the route and instead an empty GET request is send to the server bypassing the angular routing. 
So yes /map is an angular route but also available as a get request on the server. This behaviour does not occur when I change the serverside route name to something else, so it does have something to do with the name being the same. I assumed the name similarity shouldn't be a problem as angular is supposed to pick those url requests up first? Or not?

empty get request:
[image]

AuthGuard (purely checks if user is logged in clientside, backend is auth protected with each request):

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

     if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
       return true;
     } else {
        this.router.navigate(['auth', 'login']);
        return false;
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: if possible, show your `AuthGuard` too.

Comment: What happens if you change the path name from '/map', if the issue stops then you can pinpoint that the problem is the name. I assume that your hitting the get request first if you ping it directly ?

Comment: @hyper0009 Yes it is 'solved' by simply changing my server route name to eg  /maps

Answer (score 1):

So, from my knowledge you should be using the HttpClient API for making calls to the server side https://angular.io/guide/http as thats the recommended way to communicate with the server side.

Generally the frontend client side and backend should be kept separate unless your trying to create an isomorphic app which serves content both on the client and server side, which is added complexity.

Comment: Yes which I do but in this case my browser actually does the request (which angular should 'prevent' in this case).

Comment: @Stevin29 what do you mean by the 'browser makes the request', have you setup a server side get request on the same path?

Comment: Like I explain in my other comment below. I get the same behavior as described in the question, once I shut down my angular app (but let the server run) and type in the urls (any) of the server routes. And yes same path as in angular app. So angular app has /map but the server has a /map route too (which I thought should be fine).

Comment: Yea which is why i'm saying that behaviour isn't really supported in angular as its a client side app, the behaviour you expecting is isomorphism, you should take a look at Angular Universal for something like that. @Stevin29

Answer (score 0):

This is a backend issue (I guess) when serving your app. You have two options here :

1. Configure the backend to redirect on the `index.html` all the time, so whatever URL there is the backend will always redirect to the base application URL, and the frontend will actually read the routes accordingly.
2. Use the Hash location mechanism from angular, that serves this exact purpose, but you will have to update all your routes in your app (not recommended).

See the official documentation links for that :

- https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml
- https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

**EDIT :** Reading more in depth and in detail your post, it seems a bit weird and I don't know if my answer is a solution to your issue. I'll let it like that for now... maybe it'll help. If not, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reply. My backend is configured like in 1. so that is definitely not the problem. I did an other test and if I stop my angular app and just type in the routes in my browser they all have that exact behavior so I'm quite sure now that in my case as described the angular routing gets bypassed. Guess routes should be named differently then..